# Docker container can't write on host

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

First of all, I couldn't find the answer here on SO ([this is the closest post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760190/docker-container-not-able-to-write-on-host-machine)).

I have EC2 running Ubuntu. First I installed Jenkins, and then Docker.
**It's not "DonD".**

My project has a Jenkinsfile, on that I'm running some docker commands.
It's supposed to use a docker container like gradle, share a volume and build the project.

The final .war will be on the host file system.

The problem is: the gradle inside the container can't write on host's folder.

Here's my Jenkinsfile (one of countless tries):

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

node {
    checkout scm
    stage 'Gradle'

    sh 'sudo docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/api -w /api gradle gradle clean build --stacktrace'
}
```

Stacktrace important line:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create parent directory '/api/.gradle' when creating directory '/api/.gradle/4.3/fileHashes'
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the directory stored in the variable $PWD has the correct permissions to allow write in that directory?

Comment: Jenkins user: yes; I put jenkins user in the sudoers list as well;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I logged into container using the `-v` argument:

```
$ docker exec -it -v "$PWD":/api -w /api gradle bash
```

Then I tried to check the current user:

```
$ whoami
# gradle
```

So, the solution is to run the container as root:

```
sh 'docker -u root run --rm -v "$PWD":/api -w /api gradle gradle clean build'
```

This is the root of the container. Jenkins doesn't need root access.